# PHP > Zapier > Instagram with added line breaks

Tags: php, instagram, zapier

I have a string in PHP, this is sent - via email - to Zapier where it's parsed and sent on to Instagram.

However, when it is posted to IG there are no line breaks and it shows as a single block of text (very hard to read and ugly).

I've tried including all these, but no luck:

`\n` `<br>` `<p>`

How can I send a line break to IG and have it shown properly?

Comment: try to use double line breaks (i.e., two consecutive newline characters \n\n).
$message = "First line\n\nSecond line\n\nThird line";